# What do you get if you save Rabbit from the Viceroys?

Tags: watch-dogs

I screwed up and didn't notice that I could direct Rabbit while that notification popped up, so he either died or ran away somehow (I think the former is what happened). How would that situation have been different if I had saved him?

Comment: Hah, did exactly something similar last night and just came here to ask the same question.  I actually got spotted, which made all the Viceroys run around looking for me.  They killed Rabbit whilst looking for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct answer is *absolutely nothing.*

He either tells you where the ambush place is, or you retrieve the very same information automatically from his cellphone, which he drops when killed. Apart from that one dialog when he escapes ("thank you man, here's the ambush site") gameplay is not affected.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you. That's rather disappointing, but c'est la vie.

Answer (score -1):

You get a few new unlocks and about an extra hour or two of missions relating to him